# ruby - populating combobox

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two objects ingredient & origin.
each ingredient has an origin so in the ingredient I have origin_id
the view displays

```
<p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <%= @ingredient.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Origin:</b>
  <%= @ingredient.origin_id %>
</p>
```

class ingredient is declared as follows

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :recipes
  belongs_to :origin

  attr_accessible :name, :origin_id
end
```

class origin

```
class Origin < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

in the edit form I write and it works

```
<% originsArray = Origin.all.map { |origin| [origin.name, origin.id] } %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :origin_id %><br/>
    <%= f.select(:origin_id, originsArray) %><br/>
</div>
```

but if I write instead (as in all tutorials)

```
 <%= collection_select(:origin, :id, @origins, :id, :name, options ={:prompt => "-Select a payment"}, :class =>"origin") %>
```

i get

```
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

what should I fix ?

Edit 
added :

def edit
    @ingredient = Ingredient.find(params[:id])
    @origins = Origin.all
  end

Comment: "in the edit form I write and it works" - if it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: I know . but in other forms I want to change it. it is better to start to try and change something that works than something that doest. easier to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see here where @origins is declarated. It seems like your @origins is just nil and not collection.